# The need for coherent sources for interference

Tags: waves, interference

**I already know that the pattern created by non coherent sources will constantly change ( from the other answers). I want to understand why this is so**

My explanation (which I want to confirm): 
suppose 2 waves with different frequencies meet perfectly in phase at a point p at time t1. The amplitudes add. Now suppose that in the time one of the waves completes one cycle , the other covers half a cycle(different frequency) . This now creates complete destructive interference at the same point. This can happen for different combinations. Thus the pattern is not observable. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

If you have different frequencies then you never quite have a perfect point p on the atomic scale because at p plus a nanometer they are getting out of phase again and the electron in the atom (many nanometers big) has a probability to interact (observation). If you have the same frequencies but they are 180 out of phase then an electron in an atom will have a hard time to interact, however they may get scattered and slightly separated and then the probability of interaction increases again.  All these probabilities are governed by quantum mechanics.

Comment: What if we are not interested on these slight shifts? If we are only interested in the macro level observation.

Comment: On a macro scale the slight shifts due to scattering etc are what happens most often, hence you observe the photons most often.

Comment: Okay. How do we use this to explain why their is no single observable pattern with non coherent sources ( which my book claims)  ?

Comment: Check out the link from this site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364057/coherence-and-interference  Also interference is a tricky word, single photon experiments show photons want to travel a certain path of multiples of their wavelength.  Superposition is a temporary thing the energy is not cancelled.  Dark spots are where there is no energy anyway because of the paths chosen.

Comment: To avoid complication, can you answer the same question but with reference to comparatively simple water waves?

Comment: To answer your question, I don't think you are missing something. The pattern, such as it is with non coherent sources, is continuously changing i.e. not a fixed interference pattern.

Comment: @PhysicsDave,  electrons in an atom are not "many nanometers long".  An atom is on the order of a tenth of a nanometer in diameter.  "Photons want to travel a certain path of multiples of their wavelength" is simply wrong.